# proc sql count by two groups or variables

Tags: count, sas

I have some data that looks like this:

```
  ID   flag
    A        1
    A        1
    A        2
    B        1    
    B        2
    B        3
```

How do I use proc sql to count the Id by flag so that the outcome looks like this?:

```
ID   flag  count
A       1     2
A       2     1
B       1     1
B       2     1
B       3     1
```

The query I used does not seem to be correct since it returns the distinct types of flag, not how many of each type of flag there are.

```
proc sql;
select Id, flag, count(flag) as count from table
group by Id;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include `flag` in your grouping.

```
proc sql;
  select Id, flag, count(1) as count from table
    group by Id, flag;
quit;
```

Comment: Oops, that's correct - thanks!  I knew I was just missing one small thing.